# Can`t find kernel parameter CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS linux kernel 4.15

Tags: linux, драйвер, kernel, arm, embedded

Не могу найти параметр в `CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS=y` в версии ядра 4.15.

Для того, что бы мне использовать device-tree, мне необходимо выполнить 
следующиие действия

```
mount -t configfs configfs /config
mkdir /config/device-tree/overlays/test -p
```

Однако, без использования параметра CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS=y, я получаю

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/config/device-tree': Operation not permitted
```

В версии ядра 4.17 CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS убрали, соотвественно, вопрос заключается в том, что использовать вместо него?
Пробовал использовать CONFIG_CONFIGFS_FS, однако, результатов не дало.

---

I'm newbie in soc world, but i couldn`t find an answer to my question. 
I need to

```
mount -t configfs configfs /config
mkdir /config/device-tree/overlays/test -p
```

but if i make a kernel without `CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS=y` i've got a

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/config/device-tree': Operation not permitted
```

In kernel version 4.15 CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS disappeared, so the question is what should i use instead of CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS?
tried to use CONFIG_CONFIGFS_FS but without result.

Comment: Вы находитесь на русскоязычном сайте. Если вы можете прочитать и понять этот комментарий, пожалуйста, переведите вопрос на русский язык (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/768572/edit)) и расскажите, почему вы решили, что вопрос следовало написать на английском?

Comment: Я прошу прощения, я раньше задавал вопросов на stackoverflow и просто не обратил внимания на русскую версию сайта.

Comment: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/of/Kconfig Вы скачали себе какую-то хакнутую версию ядра, там чего-то напатчили, вот и мучаетесь. Из вышеприведенного файла я вижу только `OF_DYNAMIC`.

Comment: http://elektranox.org/2017/05/0020-dt-overlays/: *Sat, 27. May 2017... With DT overlays from configfs still not being available...* https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/3856491/: *March 18, 2014, 9:56 p.m.* **Вопросы?**

Answer (score 0):

При добавлении прав доступа рута:

```
sudo mkdir /config/device-tree/overlays/test -p
```

всё отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: Всё делал из под рута. Проверял права, пробовал дать /sys/ и /config права на запись, но всё без результатно.  Повторюсь, на версиях кернела младше 4.17, всё хорошо и из под рута он дает создать эти папки

Comment: Не знаю... В версии 4.6 параметр CONFIG_CONFIGFS_FS есть, а вот параметра CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS  нет.  Или я Вас не понял ?

Comment: вы правильно меня поняли и дали пищу для размышлений, почему в некоторых версия данный параметр есть, в других нету. Сравнивал версии я Linux/arm 4.13.0 и 4.15.0-rc*

Comment: Ну я смотрел тоже для ARM ! Завтра приду на работу, гляну для PowerPC.

Comment: Посмотрел для PowerPC. Там ситуация аналогичная: там есть CONFIGFS_FS ( Не CONFIG_CONFIGFS_FS !), а CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS нет совсем. Правда, это древняя версия ядра - 3.6.

Comment: смотрел для версии 4.6, в .config он присутствует. Качал с репозитория альтеры.